# Bootstrap button links stop working below breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My buttons have href's that once clicked take to a corresponding part of the page and it works fine in desktop , but when the viewport shrinks and the columns start stacking on top of each other the links on the buttons stop working. I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with the columns stacking at mobile(xs) breakpoint, however I can't figure out what breaks the links. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: provide some code to understand your problem better

Comment: Sounds like you're inadvertently hiding content and event handlers are not getting attached.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an invisible block on the button. Use your browsers DOM Explorer and try changing the CSS. Try changing display:block to inline-block or add some margin and see if you can click on the button.

Comment: As it turns out, there was something blocking it and it was another column. I was able to solve this problem by overriding the bootstrap column position from relative to static. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to help :)